# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null to accept integers

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Even though it works fine elsewhere, a problem is arising here.

```
System.out.println("How many elements u wanna put into the list?");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  //here is the problem
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Continue");
    dl.push(i);
}
```

Comment: What was the problem you are facing ? When it will throw error ? Question is unclear

Comment: You have to check that `br.readLine()` is returning a valid int. Also make sure it doesn't have any white space. Use `string.trim()` to remove white spaces.

Answer (score -1):

what do you pass in the console ? if it is a empty string you might get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Before accepting anything, it is simply showing this exception.